# ACAccountStore Facebook error

Tags: facebook, ios6

I have an app that has Facebook `user_photos` permissions enabled. The problem is if I go to Facebook and delete the app, iOS doesn't notice this. `ACAccountStore` says I have permission, so `requestAccess...` returns "granted", but as soon as I try an `SLRequest`, I get an error like `Error validating access token: User XXXXX has not authorized application YYYYY` and the app does not reappear in Facebook.

The workaround is to go to Settings->Facebook on the device, and toggle the permissions for my app off and back on. Next time I try the `requestAccess`, I get asked to confirm access again, and then the app reinstalls in Facebook and everything works.

```
ACAccountStore *accountStore = [[[ACAccountStore alloc] init] autorelease];
ACAccountType *accountType = [accountStore accountTypeWithAccountTypeIdentifier:ACAccountTypeIdentifierFacebook];

[accountStore requestAccessToAccountsWithType:accountType
                                      options:@{ACFacebookAppIdKey:       kFacebookAppID,
                                                ACFacebookPermissionsKey: @[@"user_photos"]}
                                   completion:^(BOOL granted, NSError *error)
{
   if( error ) {
      NSLog( @"account permission error %@", error );
   }
   else if( granted ) {
      NSURL *requestURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://graph.facebook.com/me/albums"];
      SLRequest *request = [SLRequest requestForServiceType:SLServiceTypeFacebook
                                              requestMethod:SLRequestMethodGET
                                                        URL:requestURL
                                                 parameters:[NSMutableDictionary dictionary]];
      NSArray *accounts = [accountStore accountsWithAccountType:accountType];
      if( [accounts count] > 0 ) {
         request.account = accounts[0];
         [request performRequestWithHandler:^ (NSData *responseData, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, NSError *error)
         {
            if( error ) {
               NSLog( @"error accessing Facebook account: %@", error );
            }
            else {
               NSDictionary *data = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:responseData options:kNilOptions error:nil];
               if( data[@"error"] != nil ) {
                  NSLog( @"error loading request: %@", data[@"error"] );
               }
               else {
                  NSLog( @"success! %@", data );
               }
            }
         }];
      }
      else {
         NSLog( @"error: no Facebook accounts" );
      }
   }
}];
```

In my case, I always get the final error ("error loading request: ") after deleting the app from Facebook, none of the other errors. After I toggle the app's permission in the device's Settings, I get success.

Comment: Just filed a bug with Apple...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to Apple, this works as intended (BS!). In practice, it turns out you have to get the `ACAccountStore` synchronized with Facebook by calling `renewCredentialsForAccount` first. In this case, the result is `ACAccountCredentialRenewResultRejected`. Then you can call `ACAccountStore requestAccessToAccountsOfType` again, and the user will finally be prompted to allow your app again.

Comment: Thank you for mentioning `renewCredentialsForAccount`! You just solved for me an error I had been stumped by for hours.

Comment: I still find it odd that it will return a ACAccountCredentialRenewResultRejected but then the next time you check the AccountStore the Account will be nil.